# Spring Data Rest Field converter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am having a hard time using my custom converters on **spring data REST project (controller free application and strictly java configuration).**

I have two Entities, an Employee and a State. The relationship is @ManyToOne, I am sure we all know that. Anyway, the problem is converting the `state` field (field name is state) from `String` to a `State` object and `setState()` in the `Employee` class for persistence to a database.

```
package com.hr.domain;

@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "state_id", nullable = true)
   private Long id;
   private String firstname;
   private State state;

   @StateConverter
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "employee_state_id_fk", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
   private State state;

   //GETTERS AND SETTERS
   public String getFirstname() {
      return firstname();
   }

   public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
      this.firstname = firstname;
   }

   public String getState() {
    return state();
   }

   public void setState(State state) {
     this.state = state;
   }

   //HASHCODES AND EQUALS

}


package com.hr.domain;

@Entity
public class State implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "state_id", nullable = true)
   private Long id;
   private String state_name;

   //GETTERS AND SETTERS

  //TO STRING
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "State [id=" + id + ", state_name=" + state_name + "]";
  }       

}
```

I have registered my converter with the conversion service but still cant get the String to be converter to State object on form submit.

```
@Bean//(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService() {       
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    bean.setConverters(getConverters());
    bean.afterPropertiesSet();
    ConversionService object = bean.getObject();
    System.out.println(object);
    return object;
}

private Set<Converter> getConverters() {    
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<Converter>();
    converters.add(new StringToStateTypeConverter());
    return converters;      
}
```

This is my StateConverter

```
@Component
@StateConverter
public class StringToStateTypeConverter implements Converter<String, State> {

    @Autowired
    StateRepository repository;

    public State convert(String source) {
        return repository.findOne(new Long(source));
    }

}
```

On submission, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB';

Any form of help will be appreciated.

May the force be with you
Regards.

**Here is the Error trace**

```
17:21:29,975 ERROR [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController] (default task-13) Could not read JSON: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.hr.domain.Employee["State"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.hr.domain.Employee["State"]): org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.hr.domain.Employee["State"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.hr.domain.Employee["State"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228) [spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]

...........
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable. (through reference chain: com.hr.domain.Employee["State"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:232) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:197) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]

Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.net.URI to type com.hr.domain.State for value 'AB'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.UriToEntityConverter.convert(UriToEntityConverter.java:106) [spring-data-rest-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:359) [spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve URI AB. Is it local or remote? Only local URIs are resolvable.
    ... 94 more
```

Comment: You should post the full stack trace.

Comment: What is the query that causes the error and what is `AB` ?

Comment: The value **AB** is a field value from a HTTP **POST** request. This is the String that needs to be converted to a State object. I added more information on the question to be more specific

Comment: AFAIK spring-data-rest works with JSON on input and output. Are you trying a different way ?

Comment: Nope. My form **POST** request is in **JSON** since I am using **ExtJS** for the UI. Which works fine with all other post requests (JSON). If I expose entity ids(which I really don't want to, since its an API too) , it works fine. The alternative I chose, was to use the State Name on submission. This state name in the request payload is what should be converted to a State object before persisting **Employee** to database

Comment: Oups, there's a lot of magic in spring-data-rest and you are trying to do something it did not expect.  Did the modification I suggested breaked anything ? If not I may have an idea ...

Comment: Haha! Magic. I like that. No it don't break anything. Feel free Serge. Share

Comment: You want to convert your string `AB` to state, so your converter will be executed with argument `source` equals `AB`, right? Could you explain me then, what behaviuor you expect in this statement `new Long(source)`?

Comment: I created that converter for testing of it's even been called. I proceeded and created a **findByState__name()** in my state repository. Still the converter doesn't get called during my HTTP**POST** request

Answer (score 1):

You a registering a new `ConversionService`. It replaces the default one that spring registers by default with a lot of converters that are generally assumed to be present. And you create a new converter instead of using your configured bean. You should instead :

- register the default conversion service of spring with all its default converters
- add you converter to this one

Your conversion service initialization could look like :

```
private @Autowired StringToStateTypeConverter stringToStateTypeConverter;

@Bean//(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService() {       
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
    bean.addConverter(String.class, State.class, stringToStateTypeConverter);
    return bean;
}
```

EDIT

As the error come from a problem of conversion from `URI` to `State`, you could try to add a converter from URI to State (assuming your repository has a method `findByName` to find a `State` by its `name`:

```
@Component
@StateConverter
public class URIToStateTypeConverter implements Converter<URI, State> {
    @Autowired
    StateRepository repository;

    public State convert(URI uri) {
        String source = uri.toString();
        try {
            long id = Long.valueOf(source);
            return repository.findOne(id);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // should be a name ??
            return repository.findByName(source);
        }
    }
}
```

And the conversion service initialization would become :

```
private @Autowired StringToStateTypeConverter stringToStateTypeConverter;
private @Autowired URIToStateTypeConverter uriToStateTypeConverter;

@Bean//(name="conversionService")
public ConversionService getConversionService() {       
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
    bean.addConverter(String.class, State.class, stringToStateTypeConverter);
    bean.addConverter(URI.class, State.class, uriToStateTypeConverter);
    return bean;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it will be used by spring-data-rest

Comment: Thank you Serge for that. I made changes on registration of my custom converter as you proposed. Is there a way to call the converter on every form post (using annotations etc)because I am still getting the error as described in the question. **Kindly Note: I am trying to avoid using controllers as much as possible**