# Posting child entities in a single request with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm playing with the [Spring Data examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples). I've defined an entity Parent that has a set of Child entities associated.

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> childs;

}

@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

And the corresponding repositories. My problem is that when posting with curl a new `Parent` with a `Child`, I run into the error `Could not read JSON document: Failed to convert from type [java.net.URI] to type` also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34583515/spring-jpa-rest-one-to-many). The answer to that question states that child entities need to be posted before, and then use the returned URL. That's the same process described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25451662/5961990) by Oliver Gierke.

Is there any way of configuring Spring Data to deserialize full child entities?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not export the repository for `Item` (by annotating the repository with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)`) you will always get the child serialized and also you can provide it with a `POST` on the parent.

But also there will be no top-level REST API endpoint for `Item` anymore and also no association resource on the parent.

You already have `cascade=ALL` on the relationship - so this approach should work.